# Mobiscroll - Change input value of a time

Tags: jquery, mobiscroll

I would like to change the input element("cookingTime").

```
 $('#cookingTime').mobiscroll({ preset: 'time', lang: 'fr', display: 'bottom', mode: 'scroller', theme: 'android' });
 $('#cookingTime').click(function () { $('#cookingTime').mobiscroll('show'); });

 $("#cookingTime").mobiscroll('setValue', result.cookingTime);
```

The last line modifies the current time when we click on the input element but doesn't modify the value of the input element.

How to do to print the right time in the input element ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the `fill` parameter to update the input value as well.

You code should look like this: `$("#cookingTime").mobiscroll('setValue', result.cookingTime, true);`

For more info see [setValue docs](http://docs.mobiscroll.com/2-12-0/datetime#!method-setValue).